# Updated react apollo cached but ui didnt update <Sharing || Solved>

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, mutation

**Must** included all data attribute inside reference as the typeDefs value. It's okies, if the value is null.

In apollo-client: 2.6.10

TypeDefs Graphql and Mutation below:

```
   type Product {
    _id: ID
    name: String!
    benefit: String
    country: String
    vitamins: [String]
    createdAt: String!
  }


  const [addFruit] = useMutation(ADD_FRUIT_MUTATION, {
    update(cache, result) {
      const cachedData = cache.readQuery({
        query: GET_FRUTIS_QUERY,
      });

      cachedData.getFruits = [
        {
          ...result.data.create_fruit, // name, vitamins, country, benefit
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(), // added this
          _id: result.data.create_fruit.name, // added this, this only temporary and must unique.
        },
        ...cachedData.getFruits,
      ];

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_FRUTIS_QUERY,
        data: { ...cachedData },
      });
    },
    onError({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) {},
    variables: fruitVariable,
  });
```

hope this helps someone. =)

I wondering why it must all included the data attribute key? if dont, it will updated cached but not into UI.

Comment: You could put a question, then answer it yourself as a `community wiki`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: cool. I see. thanks for teaching me!